# Websocket Sampler error - java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am using `Websocket Sampler plugin` in JMeter but getting below error during test execution.

```
 - Unexpected error: null
java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.ServiceSocket.getResponseMessage(ServiceSocket.java:149)
JMeter.plugins.functional.samplers.websocket.WebSocketSampler.sample(WebSocketSampler.java:159)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bug in this plugin.

Report it to maintainer or switch to alternative:

- https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src

Comment: Thanks, I have reported this issue. But found that there are already many issues that are in open status. Don't know whether it will resolved or not?

Comment: And also alternative option (https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src) does not have option to wait till response pattern matches